# Getting entity element by Name

Tags: asp.net, entity

I'm trying to create a login form with ASP.NET and entity framework. 
And I have something like this:
`Account account2 = de.Accounts.Find(accountViewModel.Account.Username);
    if(account2 != null)
    {
        if(PasswordHelper.VerifyHash(accountViewModel.Account.Password, "SHA512", account2.Password))
        {
            Session["username"] = account2.Username;
            return View("intro");
        }`

I know that the find method is to search items by Primary Key. My Primary key is "AccountID", but how can i find element by "Account" ? PLS HELP :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean find account by account number?
Whatever account property is used to identify the account, the following linq may be useful:

```
using System.Linq;

....
Account account2 = de.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Prop == value);
```

for example:

```
Account account2 = de.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == accountViewModel.Account.Username);
```